# Kafka Bytes Out lags behind Kafka Bytes In on all brokers when topics replicated with 3 and flume kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

Below is the setup detail,

Kafka with 3 brokers (each broker with 10 cores and 32GBmem (12 GB heap)).

Created topic with 120 partitions and replication factor 3.

Throughput per broker is ~40k msgs/sec and bytes in ~8mb/sec.

Flume kafka source is used as the consumer.

Observations:

When the replication factor is kept 1, the bytes out and bytes in stops exactly at same timestamp(i.e when the producer to kafka is stopped).

But when the replication factor is increased to 3, there is a time lag observed in bytes out compared to bytes in. Flume kafka source is pulling data slowly. But flume is configured with very high memory and cpu configurations.

Tried increasing num.replica.fetchers from default value 1 to 10, 20, 50 etc and replica.fetch.max.bytes from default 1MB to 10MB,20MB. But no improvement is found to be observed in terms of the lag.

under repplicated partitions is observed to be zero using replica manager metrics in jmx.

Kafka brokers were monitored for cpu and memory, cpu is being used at 3% of total cores max and memory used at 4gb (32 Gb configured).

Flume kafka source has overriden kafka consumer properties : max.partition.fetch bytes is kept at default 1MB and fetch.max.bytes is kept at default 52MB. Flume kafka source batch size is kept at default value 1000.

```
 agent.sources.****.kafka.consumer.fetch.max.bytes = 10485760
 agent.sources.****.kafka.consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes = 10485760
 agent.sources.****.batchSize = 1000
```

what more tuning is needed in order to reduce the lag between bytes in and bytes out  at kafka brokers with replication factor 3 or is there any configuration missed out?